# Difference between Swiss Manager Light and Full version?

Tags: swiss-pairing

I just realized that there are two versions of Swiss Manager. Does anyone know the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the scale of the tournament / match you need to handle. If you plan a tournament with maximum of 60 participants and 11 rounds (or a team championship up to 6 teams), the light version is enough.

If you plan to grow big, then choose the full version.

---

You can read this on the [official site](http://swiss-manager.at/general.aspx?lan=1) (last paragraph).